# Override and validate existing field in Flask Security form

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I'm trying to restrict registration in my Flask application built with Flask-Security to email addresses from specific domains.

My additional inclination was to override the `register_user` view from Flask Security, but their docs made it seem like extending the form was the preferred route.

In the following code, I attempt to add a custom validator to `email`, a field that is already declared within the Flask Security's `RegisterForm`. The additional validation function is never called. I have tried declaring the variable outside of the class and calling it from within the `EmailField`, but that doesn't seem to help either.

This is all within app.py.

```
class RestrictedRegisterForm(RegisterForm):
    email = EmailField(
        'Email', validators=[DataRequired()]
    )

    def validate_email(form, field):
        domain_list = ['foo.com', 'bar.org']
        email_domain = field.data.split("@")[1]
        if email_domain not in domain_list:
            raise ValidationError('Email address must be of an authorized domain')

user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore, register_form=RestrictedRegisterForm)
```

Comment: Shouldn't your validation method be called `validate_email` as `email` is the name of the field in the form. Also its signature should be `def validate_email(form, field):`.

Comment: You're right. That was the original incarnation, but I started switching things around once I saw that it didn't work. It's back to that form now.

Comment: I've just ran that code in one of my own projects and it works fine - I did use `InputRequired()` rather than `DataRequired()` though. How are you validating the form ?